# AWS CPP SDK JsonValue add array of double or Integer to JSON

Tags: c++, aws-sdk-cpp

i wanted to create a JSON using Aws-sdk for C++. this is what i am doing so far.

```
void convertStructToAwsJSON()
{
    Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue jsonValue = Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue();
    jsonValue.WithDouble("percentage", 93.6);
    jsonValue.WithInteger("age", 25);
    float grades[3] = {87, 95, 65};
    jsonValue.WithArray("grades", grades);
}
```

but it seems like it throws an error, saying that it is not of the argument type. I checked the documentation and the only thing I can do is add an array of type String.

```
const Aws::Utils::Array<Aws::String> grades;
grades[0] = "87";
grades[1] = "95";
grades[2] = "65";
jsonValue.WithArray("grades", grades);
```

Now it works. How to store it in double or integer instead of string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright got a response from the AWS SDK Team. It can be done like this:

```
Aws::Utils::Array<Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue> grades(2);
Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue value1;
Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue value2;
grades[0] = value1.AsDouble(3.1416);
grades[1] = value2.AsDouble(164635242.4134452);
```

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/1526